# How to loop SDL_Surface?

Tags: c, sdl

I am making a mini rpg tile game and I have an issue.
There are going to be 208 tiles on the screen and here comes my problem(using SDL)

How do you create multiple surfaces without it looking like this:

[image]

Would there be a loop for these kind of things? This doesn't look healthy at all

Comment: is that really required? I have no problem other than 
SDL_Surface* Tile1 = NULL;
SDL_Surface* Tile2 = NULL; 
I just need to know if it can be looped .w.

Comment: I think there is a deeper problem here. Pick a book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I meant to declare all the Surfaces in int Game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an array like

```
SDL_Surface* Tiles[208];
```

or a pointer to pointer to SDL_Surface and initialize it properly

```
SDL_Surface **tiles;
```

Comment: it worked pretty well ! Thank you ! but when i do Tiles[207] = SDL_LoadBMP("tiles/88.bmp"); it's not working ow // EDIT: I mean it's working for the declaration part but how do i attribute to, let's say Tile 206 an image?

Comment: @Yoshipouki Dude, pick a C book for beginners.